# How do I fall through in a bash case statement in OSX?

Tags: macos, bash

I have some bash scripts that I would like to run in OSX, but some of them contain the fallthrough case terminator ';&' which doesn't seem to work on Mac. Here's sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
    test)
        echo "go" ;&    
    test)
        echo "go2" ;;
esac
```

In Cygwin, .\test.sh test produces

```
go
go2
```

but on OSX,

```
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
./test.sh: line 4: `            echo "go" ;&
```

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, so I apologize if it is a dumb suggestion, but what happens if you use ;| instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works as is on my ubuntu system, bash 4.2.24.

I think you are using an earlier version of bash which doesn't support `;&` fall-through which was added since bash 4.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement):

```
Fall through is done using ;& (new since Bash 4) whereas ;; acts as a case break.
```

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7 Lion & 10.8 Mountain Lion include `bash` 3.2.48, not `bash` 4.x, so fall-through will not be supported.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could try using `/bin/zsh` instead of `/bin/bash`? Your sample code works with “zsh 4.3.9” but not “bash 3.2.48” on my MacOS X 10.6.8.

Otherwise, the script has to be rewritten in some way… but it's hard to say exactly how without knowing what it does. Simply duplicating the code as needed is probably the simplest option and should work in every case.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, MacOS users are stuck with bash 3.2 for the time being.